# Ignoring [Required] data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Why is MVC still validating this property as I already excluded it?

```
...
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter activation code")]
public string ActivationCode { get; set; }
...
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult CreateAccount([Bind(Exclude = "ActivationCode ")] AccountCreationViewModel m, string returnUrl)
...
```

Comment: Why are you excluding properties from binding? I see that you are using view models. The way to exclude a property from a view model is simply not to define it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are excluding the ActivationCode here from being able to be bound to your view model.

However the ModelBinding will still validate the complete model.

I would suggest creating a new ViewModel for your purpose, or a filter as suggested by Steve Sanderson [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/02/19/partial-validation-in-aspnet-mvc-2/)

Comment: Thanks, Swaff. I've just read Steve Sanderson's Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework and he didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it does exactly the same as what you have but I have done something like this and it has worked.

```
[ValidateInput(true, Exclude="ActivationCode")]
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult CreateAccount(AccountCreationViewModel m, string returnUrl)
```

Comment: ValidateInputAttribute doesn't have Exclude member.

Comment: @Eduardo I think it was added in MVC3 according to [this post](http://naikvinay.wordpress.com/2010/11/08/validateinputattribute-changes-in-mvc3/). You didn't mention which version you were using.